# OOP Access to class variables through function ex : FunctionName()->SomeVariable

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, woocommerce

As i know in oop in order to get access to a variables of some class we need to do something like that

```
$foo = new Foo; 
echo $foo->cart
```

but in a php file in woocommerce I found something like that

```
WC()->cart;
```

So i want to know how they access to a class variables just through a function without any object ?  thank you for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [WooCommerce docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-WC.html):

> **Function WC**
>
> Main instance of WooCommerce.
>
> Returns the main instance of WC to prevent the need to use globals.

So the `WC()` function itself returns an object. From there, you can operate on it like any other. As a very cut-down example:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    public $id = 123;
}

function foo() {
    return new Foo;
}

echo foo()->id; // 123;
```